# php echo javascript alert() not working

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to display a popup message when user is logged out, so I use

```
echo "<script>alert(\"You are logged out\");</script>";
```

But it doesn't work.

Below is my coding. Is there any logic problem in my coding?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) == "admin")
{
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
@import "../CSS/Style.css";
@import "../CSS/Admin.css";
</style>
<title>Admin Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="body"></div>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']) == "logout")
    {
        session_destroy();
        echo "<script>alert(\"You are logged out\");</script>";
        header("Location: ..\Main.php");
    }
    else
    {
?>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="ManageStaff.php">Manage Staff</a>
</div>

<div class="menu2">
    <a href="ManageAccount.php">Manage Account</a>
</div>

<div class="logout">
    <a href="AdminHomePage.php?id=logout">Logout</a>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
else
{
?>
<center>
<p style="font-size:50px; font-weight:bold">Access Denied</p>
<p style="font-size:18px">Your request for this page has been denied because of access control</p>
</center>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The session will be destroyed and will also redirect to Main.php, just the `alert()` will not come out.

Comment: Firstly, you're not using `isset()` correctly [[docs](https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)]. Secondly, you can't use `header()` after output has been sent. Again, this is clearly stated in the php docs: https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php. Finally, assuming you could, how do you expect your code to work? You can't mix PHP and Javascript; if you're using php to redirect the user, this would happen before anything is sent to the user, thus the javascript alert would never fire. You really need to think about your solution a bit more.

Comment: `isset` will only ever return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing an echo and then writing a relocate header. If you did your relocate in the javascript (after the user clicked the alert), it would probably work the way you expect it to.

```
echo "<script>alert('You are logged out'); window.location.href='..\Main.php';</script>";
```

Also, the way that you use `isset` will cause problems because `isset` returns true or false (it checks if a value is present), rather than returning the value.

So instead of

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) == "admin")
```

You need to do:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) && $_SESSION['Username'] == "admin")
```

Comment: That's true; he does ask if there's 'any logic problem in my coding', and his misuse of `isset` will cause his logic to malfunction. I answered his actual question, which seemed to be about why his alert wasn't visible, the answer to which is that his redirect caused it never to be processed by the browser.

Comment: I think you'll find that the actual reason is misuse of isset causes the whole page to always inform you that there is an access violation. Also, the header call after output would also cause an error because headers have already been sent by that point.

Answer (score 2):

`header("Location: ..\Main.php");` tells the browser to go to another page before it even shows the page... if you want the user to see the alert, try this:

```
session_destroy();
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('You are logged out');";
echo "window.location = '../Main.php';"; // redirect with javascript, after page loads
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 2):

use this it will solve your problem!! first change your code from

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) == "admin")
{
```

to

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['Username']) && ($_SESSION['Username']=="admin")){
```

and than use following code

```
 if(!empty($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id']=="logout"))
        {
          session_destroy();?>
             <script>
             alert("You are logged out");
             window.location.href='..\Main.php';
             </script>
           <?php }?>
```

Comment: @bob yeah.. i no just updating

Answer (score -1):

Try,
This must work,
And remove php header, replace with the following code.

```
 echo "<script>alert('You are logged out');
 location.href='..\Main.php';
 </script>";
```